# How to check variable against 2 possible values?

Tags: python

I have a variable s which contains a one letter string

```
s = 'a'
```

Depending on the value of that variable, I want to return different things. So far I am doing something along the lines of this:

```
if s == 'a' or s == 'b':
   return 1
elif s == 'c' or s == 'd':
   return 2
else: 
   return 3
```

Is there a better way to write this? A more Pythonic way? Or is this the most efficient?

Previously, I incorrectly had something like this:

```
if s == 'a' or 'b':
   ...
```

Obviously that doesn't work and was pretty dumb of me.

I know of conditional assignment and have tried this:

```
return 1 if s == 'a' or s == 'b' ...
```

I guess my question is specifically to is there a way you can compare a variable to two values without having to type `something == something or something == something`

Comment: Question: what are you doing with this code? Are you switching command line options, because if you are you should look at the `getopt` module instead.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
if s in ('a', 'b'):
    return 1
elif s in ('c', 'd'):
    return 2
else:
    return 3
```

Comment: @pythonrubies - if this is what you were looking for, accept it as the answer.   @Jesse - I would recommend using tuples instead of lists for your code snippet.

Comment: Quick question, is there any difference between @Jesse Dhillon answer and @Tim Pietzcker?

Comment: Tim's will only work for strings, this will work for any object that you can test equality against.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, does anyone know if this actually speeds up the process at all? I mean, does it save processor time, or just programmer time?

Comment: @pythonrubies: Tim's answer would also return `1` or `2` if `s` was `ab` or `cd`.

Comment: @Shaded: The construction of the list may actually make it slightly slower than the two separate tests. In practice it will probably be an insignificant difference. You should profile the code rather than trying to guess if performance is a real concern.

Comment: @Shaded Did a quick timeit test. if-or is 5.57 usec/func and if-in is 5.22 usec/func (over 10M iterations).

Comment: @Mark Byers: I was just curious, I don't work with Python but just from a low level perspective it seems like it would add a few extra steps for the processor, however negligible it might be :) Thanks for the response!

Comment: @shookster: Wow! I would not have expected that, thanks for taking the time to do some tests!

Comment: It seems it is faster then comparing them separetely? from @shookster's tests. Also, would using the conditional assignment be more 'pythonic' then writing out the if-else?

Comment: @Jesse, @Matthew: why are tuples better than lists for this?  Won't they both work?

Comment: @Dan, two reasons. First, tuples are immutable so semantically it makes sense to use them for values that don't change. In this case, you will always be comparing against `a, b, c, d` and those values are known at compile time, so the semantically correct solution would be to use an immutable type. Second, related to the first, there is a performance/efficiency boost when you use tuples, and I don't remember the details but you would expect tuples to use less memory and instantiate faster.

Answer (score 15):

```
 d = {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':2}
 return d.get(s, 3)
```

Comment: I'd say this is fairly clever.

Comment: Now I am curious if this is faster.

Comment: It could even be reduced further: `return {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':2}.get(s, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

If you only return fixed values, a dictionary is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
if s in 'ab':
    return 1
elif s in 'cd':
    return 2
else:
    return 3
```

Comment: As @Jesse Dillon noted, this only works with strings, and would also return 1 if `s=='ab'`, but the constraints of the question were specific about this - `s` is a one-letter string.

Comment: Right, I wouldn't say that this is wrong given the parameters of the question. +1 for demonstrating that `__contains__` is a predicate for testing the existence of substrings within strings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe little more self documenting using if else:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':2} ## good choice is to replace case with dict when possible
return d[s] if s in d else 3
```

Also it is possible to implement the popular first answer with if else:

```
  return (1 if s in ('a', 'b') else (2 if s in ('c','d') else 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return 1 if (x in 'ab') else 2 if (x in 'cd') else 3
```

Comment: this would allow `x` to be `'ab'` or `'cd'`

Comment: @SilentGhost: the intent is to solve the proposed problem not a variant, OP said "I have a variable s which contains a one letter string"

Comment: Just put 'ab' and 'cd' as list('ab') and list('cd') then x cannot be the 'ab' and 'cd' combination.