# Python If not dont really works

Tags: python, verification

I tryed to make a Verification system, but it dont really Works well.

If i choose username Fynn or LeQuit this ist the output

```
Welcome Fynn

You are not LeQuit or Fynn
```

But its not what i need i need it to choose 1, Like if i  type a random name Example:dfgdfdfgd

it still  says the Same...

My code

```
if username == "LeQuit" or "Fynn":
    print("Welcome " + username)
if not username == "LeQuit" or "Fynn":
    print("You are not LeQuit or Fynn ")
```

Comment: `if username in {"LeQuit", "Fynn"}` and `if username not in {"LeQuit", "Fynn"}`. But in that code better to use `else`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check variable against 2 possible values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3260057/2745495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many users in your system - the code below is the right way to go.
It keeps the users in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and check against the set

```
registered_users = {"LeQuit","Fynn","Other users..."}
if username in registered_users: 
    print(f"Welcome {username}")
else:
    print("f{username} is not a registered user")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your haven't used the `or` correctly. Here is the correct code:

```
if username == "LeQuit" or username == "Fynn":
    print("Welcome " + username)
else:
    print("You are not LeQuit or Fynn ")
```

Comment: Thank you Very much, i cant mark this answer as Helpful i have to wait 7 minutes, but i gonna definitly do it :D