Probleme with if elif that always return the same value in python
i'm new in coding and I got in touble.
I tried to create a code that asks question about the Child-Pugh score. But answer_child always return [] and total return always 1.
here is the code :
from random import *

child = []
x =["Absente", "Stade 1", "Stade 2", "Stade 3", "Stade 4"]
y = ["Absente", "Discrète", "Abondante"]
encephalopathie = choice(x)
ascite = choice(y)
bilirubine = randint(15,70)
albumine = randint(15, 45)
TP = randint(5, 80)
total = 0
if TP > 50 :
    total =+1
elif 40 <= TP <= 50 :
    total =+2
elif TP < 40 :
    total =+3


if albumine > 35 :
    total =+1
elif 28 <= albumine <= 35 :
    total =+2
elif albumine < 28 :
    total =+3

if bilirubine < 35 :
    total =+1
elif 35 <= bilirubine <= 50 :
    total =+2
elif bilirubine > 50 :
    total =+3

if encephalopathie == ["Absente"] :
    total =+1
elif encephalopathie == ["Stade 1", "Stade 2"] :
    total =+2
elif encephalopathie == ["Stade 3", "Stade 4"]:
    total =+3

if ascite == ["Absente"] :
    total =+1
elif ascite == ["Discrète"] :
    total =+2
elif ascite == ["Abondante"]:
    total =+3

if 5<= total <= 6 :
    child = ["A"]
elif 7 <= total <= 9 :
    child = ["B"]
elif total >= 10 :
    child = ["c"]

print('Tp =', TP, "Bilirubine =", bilirubine, "Albumine =", albumine, "Ascite =", ascite, "Encephalopathie =", encephalopathie)
answer_int = input("Quel est la cotation du score en chiffre ?")
int(answer_int)
answer_child = input("Quel est le score de Child-Pugh ? A, B ou C ?")


if answer_child == child and answer_int == total :
    print("Vrai")
else :
    print("Faux, la bonne réponse est Child",child, total)

I tried to change the last elif with else, but didn't work out.
thanks for your help

You are putting a lot of your strings in one-element lists, for no apparent reason.  A list is never equal to a string, no matter what value is contained in the list.

Also, doing int(answer_int) doesn't modify the value already stored in answer_int. You're converting the user's input to an integer, and then throwing that integer away because you don't assign it to anything. You need to assign the value returned by the int(...) function call to a variable, e.g. answer_int = int(answer_int)

Now's a good time to learn debugging. If you step through your code in a debugger, you'll see what values each variable contains, and you'll be able to understand why your conditions don't work.

And to check if a variable is one of two values, variable == [value1, value2] is incorrect -- this checks if variable is a list containing value1 and value2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260057/how-to-check-variable-against-2-possible-values

total =+1 This simply assigns total to 1, erasing whatever value it already had.  You want +=, not =+.

answer_child is a str and child is list[str] which means answer_child == child always will be false.
Furthermore answer_int is actually a str while total is an int which means answer_int == total also will be false no matter what.
So answer_child == child and answer_int == total will never be true.
I am guessing you also should write total += YOUR_NUMBER instead of total =+ YOUR_NUMBER, since the latter will change total to YOUR_NUMBER, not add it.

Thanks you for your answer. I will see how to convert list to string and string to int if it is possible.
